# Transpose and paste to a running list

Tags: excel, vba

I need to transpose and paste data from table on sheets("SCAN IN").column("C2:ZZ")and paste to lastrow of sheets ("SCAN IN2") to create a running list. Then Clear the table on sheets("SCAN IN")

I have set the form to transpose from sheets("SCAN IN") and clear contents of the destination sheet then paste the data in columns ("C2:D").

```
Sub Transfer_Transpose_Scans()
    Dim WksScanIn As Worksheet
    Dim rBinLocs As Range
    Dim rBinLoc As Range
    Dim iOutputRow As Long
    Dim iColOffset As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long


    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set WksScanIn = Worksheets("SCAN IN")
    On Error GoTo NoBinLocs
    Set rBinLocs = WksScanIn.Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Worksheets("SCAN IN2").Activate
    Range("C2:D" & Rows.Count).ClearContents




    iOutputRow = 1

    For Each rBinLoc In rBinLocs
        iColOffset = 1
        While Len(rBinLoc.Offset(0, iColOffset).Value) > 1
            iOutputRow = iOutputRow + 1
            Cells(iOutputRow, "C").Value = rBinLoc.Value
            Cells(iOutputRow, "D").Value = rBinLoc.Offset(0, iColOffset).Value
            iColOffset = iColOffset + 1
        Wend
    Next rBinLoc

    Exit Sub
NoBinLocs:
    MsgBox "No bin locations found on " & """" & "SCAN IN" & """" & " worksheet Column c", vbInformation, "No Bin Locations Found"
End Sub
```

I need to copy, transpose , paste from Sheets("SCAN IN").column(C2:D) to the last row of the table on ("SCAN IN2").column(c:d).

I want to clear data that was transposed and copied from sheets("SCAN IN").

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunctions.Transpose()` applied to all the cells. Use the `.Resize()` function to pick multiple cells. Like `Range("C2").Resize(5,2)` is equivalent to `Range("C2:D6")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Transfer_Transpose_Scans()
Dim WksScanIn As Worksheet
Dim rBinLocs As Range
Dim rBinLoc As Range
Dim iOutputRow As Long
Dim iColOffset As Long
Dim lastrow As Long


ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set WksScanIn = Worksheets("SCAN IN")
On Error GoTo NoBinLocs
Set rBinLocs = WksScanIn.Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
On Error GoTo 0

Worksheets("SCAN IN2").Activate
'Range("C2:D" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

iOutputRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rBinLoc In rBinLocs
    iColOffset = 1
    While Len(rBinLoc.Offset(0, iColOffset).Value) > 1
        iOutputRow = iOutputRow + 1
        Cells(iOutputRow, "C").Value = rBinLoc.Value
        Cells(iOutputRow, "D").Value = rBinLoc.Offset(0, iColOffset).Value
        iColOffset = iColOffset + 1
    Wend
Next rBinLoc

WksScanIn.Range("C2:XFD" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

Exit Sub
```

Comment: It took me a minute but I figured it out.

Comment: You know you don't need to copy one cell at a time, but you can copy multiple cells arranged in a table. For example to copy a row of 10 cells between two sheets type `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(1,10).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(1,10).Value`